# Svg background overriding browser color?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am making a landing page with two variations of a logo: a blue and white variation. This is best illustrated by an example:

```css
/**
 * Main Color: rgb(130, 153, 230)
 */

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(130, 153, 230);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

section.hero {
  margin-top: 30vh;
  width: 75vw;
  max-width: 300px;
}

header nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;

  display: flex;
}

header nav img {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 8px;
  margin: 8px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Mann Robotics | Robotics Organization in Greenville, SC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="hero">
      <img src="https://rawgit.com/MayorMonty/a2b6198126e10a2412acacf6a0a13459/raw/25ca1cc16d3dafb662ed6b32029c24d5d19c6877/logo-blue.svg" alt="Mann Robotics Logo">
    </nav>
    <section class="hero">
      <img src="https://rawgit.com/MayorMonty/a2b6198126e10a2412acacf6a0a13459/raw/25ca1cc16d3dafb662ed6b32029c24d5d19c6877/logo-white.svg" alt="Mann Robotics Logo">
    </section>
  </header>
  <div style="height: 100vh"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or see this GIF recreating the issue in my browser, Chrome[image]

Notice how the white background becomes transparent, beyond just itself! It makes the parent `<header>` transparent as well. This baffles me and interestingly enough when you embed an `<svg>` into the `<html>` itself, the strange behavior disappears?

Thoughts, Solutions, Explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `<svg>` transparency here, it's just an illusion. Your nav element (the small one) is always there, sitting on top, because of

```
header nav {
  position: fixed;
}
```

You don't notice it, because the only colors in that `<img>` are:

- transparent
- *crazy blue* (which is the background).

Add this code and you'll see it:

```
header nav img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

P.S: The cake is a lie.

Comment: Oh this is sneaky! Thanks!